# Expectation in a stochastic differential equation

Tags: itos-lemma, sde

I'm new to stochastic calculus, I want to find the mean of $X_2$ with $X_t = \exp(W_t)$, with $W_t$ a Wiener process.

I used Ito's Lemma is arrive at the SDE:
\begin{align}
d(X_t) = \frac{1}{2}X_t dt + X_t dW_t
\end{align}
But how can I get the mean of $X_2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about *unconditional expectation*, in general you have

$$
\mathbb{E}[X_t] = \mathbb{E}[e^{W_t}] = e^{\mathbb{E}[W_t] + \frac{1}{2}\text{Var}(W_t) }
$$

which yields

$$
\mathbb{E}[X_t]= e^{\frac{1}{2} t}
$$

Hence,

$$ \mathbb{E}[X_2]= e $$

Comment: I'm quite new to the theory. What is the name of the first equality and under which hypotheses is it true?

Comment: @Victor the first equality comes from the moment-generating function of a normal. Take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176196/calculate-the-expected-value-of-y-ex-where-x-sim-n-mu-sigma2) for more details. In general, $\mathbb{E}[e^X] = e^{\mu + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2}$ holds whenever $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$